# PHP SoapClient - Possible name spacing issues - non-wsdl mode

Tags: php, web-services, soap, wsdl

I previously managed to call a .NET service using PHP's SoapClient library without too many issues, but now I face a scenario where I have to access the same services in non-WSDL mode.

I seem to have created, more or less, the correct XML structure to send through to the service, but the server does not seem to be picking up the variables I am sending.

Based on output from SOAPUI, I should be attempting to generate the following SOAP call:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:int="http://someservices.com/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <int:getService>
         <int:foo>String value for foo</int:foo>
         <int:bar>String value for bar</int:bar>
      </int:getService>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

The output that I am generating with SOAPClient is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:ns1="http://someservices.com" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:enc="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-encoding">
<env:Body>
        <ns1:getService env:encodingStyle="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-encoding">
            <foo xsi:type="xsd:string">String value for foo</foo>
            <bar xsi:type="xsd:string">String value for bar</bar>
        </ns1:getService>
    </env:Body>
</env:Envelope>
```

The error returned from the .NET service is "bar expected!" - indicating, at the very least, that the service is not picking up my second parameter.

I am constructing my soap call using the following:

```
$foo = 'String value for foo';
$bar = 'String value for bar';    

$options = array(
                     'trace' => 1,
                     'exceptions' => 1,
                     'uri' => 'http://someservices.com',
                     'soapaction' => 'http://someservices.com/getService',
                     'soap_version' => SOAP_1_2,
                     'type_map' => array('type_ns' => 'int')
                     );

$response = $soapclient->__soapCall('getService', array( new SoapParam($foo, 'foo'), new SoapParam($bar, 'bar')), $options);
```

I am not sure what the issue is. Right now I am guessing that it might be an xmlns attribute issue. Note that the SOAPUI call specifies the int: in front of the function calls and parameters. I have tried to specify this xmlns but without luck. As you can see xmlns generated by Soap Client call is:

```
xmlns:ns1
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

As it turns out, having the namespace labelled as ns1 instead of int was not the issue.

The problem was that the getService parameter was being prefixed with the namespace ns1, whilst the variables foo and bar were not.

As such, this was resolved by appending "ns1:" to the Soap Params in the soapCall function, as follows:

```
$response = $soapclient->__soapCall('getService', array( new SoapParam($foo, 'ns1:foo'), new SoapParam($bar, 'ns1:bar')), $options);
```